# The convertion between iplimage and avframe

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

Now I use sws_scale to convert an avframe to iplimage, then use opencv to do some operations to the image, then convert the iplimage to avframe, but the image seems becoming more purple than the origin image. This is my code

```
int av2ipl(AVFrame *src, IplImage *dst, int height, int width)
{ 
    struct SwsContext *swscontext = sws_getContext(width, height, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, dst->width, dst->height, PIX_FMT_BGR24, SWS_BILINEAR, 0, 0, 0); 
    if (swscontext == 0) 
        return 0; 
    int linesize[4] = {dst->widthStep, 0, 0, 0 }; 
    sws_scale(swscontext, src->data, src->linesize, 0, height, (uint8_t **) & (dst->imageData), linesize); 
    return 1; 
}

int ipl2av(IplImage* src, AVFrame* dst, int height, int width)
{
    struct SwsContext *swscontext = sws_getContext(width, height, PIX_FMT_BGR24,     width, height, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BILINEAR, 0, 0, 0); 
    if(swscontext == 0)
        return 0;
    int linesize[4] = {src->widthStep, 0, 0, 0};
    sws_scale(swscontext, (uint8_t **) & (src->imageData), linesize, 0, height, dst-       >data, dst->linesize);
    return 1;
}
```

Is there any wrong in the code?

Comment: Can you post example images?